# Writing a book about what you thought while stuck in a situation

Tags: creative-writing

I wrote a book about everything I thought while stuck in a certain situation I have only partially come out of throughout many years (sort of like Anne Frank, but I don't think I'm as wise). Do you think my book would be able to be received with a good audience?

Comment: Hi Jack and welcome to Writers.  This is very broad right now; how successful your book is depends on the quality of the writing, the market you're targeting, the particular difficult situation (how much people can relate to it), whether you're somebody famous (so people are interested in *you*), and probably other things.  I'm going to put this on hold; you can [edit] to focus the question more and then the community will review for reopening.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about the kinds of questions that work well here.  Thanks.

Comment: How are some ways I could focus my question more? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain why you think your particular book would not be well received? Because of the subject matter? The writing style?

Comment: My book is mostly about my thoughts and thought processes and related trouble brought about. I was thinking that with all the information available on the internet these days such as on stack exchange, Wikipedia, and YouTube, my book will be worthless. Why would anyone care about my documented thought processes and experiences, no matter how unique and representative these may be? Plus, since these took place over several years, they may even be outdated. Thanks.

Comment: To be frank, there's no way for a web community to guess whether your book will be well-received or not. It depends on so many factors, including how good your writing is, how you publish and market it, whether it finds an audience it resonates with, and sheer luck. (Also, bear in mind that the vast majority of _all books_ aren't particularly well-received.) We can't tell you whether or not to write the book. Do you have a difficulty holding you back now, beyond "Should I write this book?"

Comment: Could you please provide some evidence for your statement that all books aren't particularly well received? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter how your book is received. What matters is that you write the book of your heart before you die. If this is that book, don't worry about what anyone else thinks and go for it. No matter what anyone else will think, you will know that you wrote your soul onto paper. Or something like that. Good luck!